# Selecting a File with File Dialog From Function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use below code to selecting a file and write it's path and filename to textbox. I tried from a Worksheet with codename `TESTAREA` But i'm always get an error Type Mismatch.

I'm using below procedure to use function from sheet TEST_AREA(TESTAREA) Sheet Name (Code Name)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call myFunctions.SelectFile(TESTAREA, "*.txt", TextBox1)
End Sub
```

This is function

```
Function SelectFile(ByVal strSheetName As Worksheet, strFilterExt As String, strTextBox As TextBox)

    Dim fdo As Office.FileDialog
    Set fdo = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fdo
      .InitialFileName = AUTOMBS.path
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Please select the file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", strFilterExt
      If .Show = True Then
          strSheetName.strTextBox.Value = .SelectedItems(1)
      End If
   End With

End Function
```

Could you please help me where i'm wrong ?

Comment: Which line generates the error?

Comment: On this line: `strSheetName.strTextBox.Value` if `str...` actually denotes a string rather than a sheet/ textbox then it will throw errors...

Comment: @AndyG it gives only an error Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch and only option OK and Help there's no Debug option.

Comment: @CallumDA you mean make all of them string ?

Comment: Where have defined TESTAREA? It won't readily recognise this as a sheet's codename.

Comment: Is `TESTAREA` global? Can't see it defined here.

Comment: @AndyG, I'm just saying you've probably named your variables badly. You're making them look like strings (with str...) however, they aren't strings -- they are worksheet and textbox objects. Otherwise you would have got a compile time error, rather than run time

Comment: Do you mean `Call myFunctions.SelectFile("TESTAREA", "*.txt", TextBox1)`?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost You mean only problem with " ?

Comment: @CallumDA It could be do you know how to achieve this ?

Comment: @AntiDrondert TESTAREA is my sheet's codename

Comment: @AndyG TESTAREA is one of my sheet where my textbox and command button exists.

Comment: Is your TextBox a MSForms TextBox or an ActiveX TextBox?

Comment: @CallumDA is it ActiveX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I added an *ActiveX TextBox* to *Sheet1* and used your code. It gave me a *Type Mismatch* until I changed the function to take a `MSForms.TextBox` instead.

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetName(Sheet1.TextBox1)
End Sub

Function GetName(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    GetName = tb.Value
End Function
```

---

So try this. I changed it to a `Sub` because you aren't returning anything to the `Function`!

```
Sub SelectFile(ByVal strSheetName As Worksheet, strFilterExt As String, strTextBox As MSForms.TextBox)

    Dim fdo As Office.FileDialog
    Set fdo = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fdo
      .InitialFileName = AUTOMBS.path
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Title = "Please select the file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", strFilterExt
      If .Show = True Then
          strTextBox.Value = .SelectedItems(1)
      End If
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: that's worked with me so i removed Worksheet value from procedure inputs. Thank you.